# Is there a way to use the distances of the two opposite apsides to determine the eccentricity of an orbit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

Is there a way to use the distances of the two opposite apsides to determine the eccentricity of an orbit? The ratio between the distances (i.e. perihelion & aphelion) seem like they'd have a straightforward relationship with the eccentricity of the orbit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Derivation is pretty straightforward.
Ellipse semi-major axis is arithmetic mean of perihelion & aphelion :

$$ \tag 1 a = \frac {r_{max}+r_{min}}{2}$$

while semi-minor axis is geometric mean of maximum and minimum distances from foci :
$$ \tag 2 b = \sqrt {r_{max} \cdot r_{min}} $$

And since the eccentricity of an ellipse is defined as :

$$ \tag 3 e = \sqrt {1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}} $$ ,

substituting (1) and (2) into 3-rd, gives :

$$\begin{align}
 \tag 4 e &= \sqrt {1-\frac{4 \cdot r_{max} \cdot r_{min}}{(r_{max}+r_{min})^2}} \\
&=\sqrt {\frac{(r_{max}+r_{min})^2}{(r_{max}+r_{min})^2}-\frac{4 \cdot r_{max} \cdot r_{min}}{(r_{max}+r_{min})^2}}\\
&=\sqrt {\frac{r_{max}^2+r_{min}^2+2 \cdot r_{max} \cdot r_{min} - 4 \cdot r_{max} \cdot r_{min}}{(r_{max}+r_{min})^2}}\\
&=\sqrt {\frac{r_{max}^2+r_{min}^2 - 2 \cdot r_{max} \cdot r_{min}}{(r_{max}+r_{min})^2}}\\
&=\sqrt {\frac{(r_{max}-r_{min})^2}{(r_{max}+r_{min})^2}}\\
&=\boxed {\frac{r_{max}-r_{min}}{r_{max}+r_{min}}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: With a little bit of algebra you can simplify your final expression
even further and get $$e=\frac{r_\max-r_\min}{r_\max+r_\min}$$

Comment: Thanks, simplified.